# Elegant way to provide flatting iterator for vector of vectors

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, c++14

I have an adapter, whose goal is to provide **forward iterator** for pair values `pair<FeatureVector, Label>`. However in my internal representation I store data as `vector<pair<vector<strings>, Label>>`.

So during iterations, I need to flatten it and convert every single `string`, which is short sentence like "oil drops massively today", to `FeatureVector`

In raw variant I have something like:

```
{
  {"Oil drops massively","OPEC surge oil produciton","Brent price goes up" -> "OIL_LABEL"}, 
  {"France consume more vine", "vine production in Italy drops" -> "VINE_LABEL"}
}
```

and I need to convert it to:

```
{
  vectorize("Oil drops massively") -> "OIL_LABEL", 
  vectorize("OPEC surge oil produciton") -> "OIL_LABEL", ... , 
  vectorize("vine production in Italy drops") -> "VINE_LABEL"
}
```

`vectorize()` -> it's a conversion from sentence to sparse vector like this `"Oil drops on NYSE" -> {0,1,0..0,1,0..0,1}`

The simpliest way will be create new vector and initialize it with all data and than use it's iterators, but this is pretty resource havy operation, so ideally I want this kind of conversion to be done over each iteration. What is the most elegant way for such kind of conversion?

This is a simplified version of data structure for storing text corpus. Iterators later need to be used in classifier initialization, which require 2 iterators: `begin` and `end` which is logically similar to the same as in `vector`.

Comment: How exactly do you need to iterate?  `for(:)` loop one-at-a-time only?

Comment: You need to convert each `string` in the `vector` to a `FeatureVector` or you need to convert the `vector<string>` into a `FeatureVector`?

Comment: What is `FeatureVector`? You need to flatten what into what?

Comment: No, that doesn't help.  "I need a begin and end iterator" doesn't tell me exactly how these iterators will be used.  Do they need to be random access iterators?  Forward iterators?  Input iterators?  Please tell me the *weakest* iterator that you need.  The more you require, the harder and more expensive the solution.  Second question: is boost acceptable?

Comment: each separate string converting to feature vector

Comment: You could be slightly less imprecise. For example, "convert `string` to `FeatureVector`" is ... (1) to construct a `FeatureVector` from a single `string`, or (2) to construct a `FeatureVector` from a `vector<string>`, or (3) something else.

Comment: Third question(s): is making a flattened copy acceptable?  Would you prefer the iterators generate their contents as they iterate?  (If you demand no copy, the answer *may* be impossible depending on how you answered other questions).  These questions are all designed to narrow down which of many solutions is best for your problem, please try to answer them to the best of your ability!

Comment: @Yakk I updated question again. Answering for your last question - ideally it's better to parse strings on each iteration, since it's time consuming operation and not all of data need to be required immidiatelly. However if it's make implementation much harder, than simplified version could be ok.

Comment: To avoid gross inefficiency I would design `FeatureVector` to be able to only reference an external string.

Comment: See [this link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_tags) describing iterator types.  Input iterator is the weakest, and corresponds roughly to what you can do if you are reading data from a file in order, for example.  Do you need forward or input?  Input is an order of magnitude easier.  Thanks, sorry for the bold, didn't see it!

Answer (score 1):

A simple range type:

```
template<class It>
struct range_t {
  It b{},e{};
  It begin() const {return b;}
  It end() const {return e;}
  bool empty() const {return begin()==end();}
  friend bool operator==(range_t lhs, range_t rhs){
    if (lhs.empty() && rhs.empty()) return true;
    return lhs.begin() == rhs.begin() && lhs.end() == rhs.end();
  }
  friend bool operator!=(range_t lhs, range_t rhs){
    return !(lhs==rhs);
  }
  range_t without_front( std::size_t N = 1 ) const {
    return { std::next(begin(), N), end() };
  }
  range_t without_back( std::size_t N = 1 ) const {
    return { begin(), std::prev(end(),N) };
  }
  decltype(auto) front() const {
    return *begin();
  }
  decltype(auto) back() const {
    return *std::prev(end());
  }
};
template<class It>
range_t<It> range( It b, It e ) {
  return {b,e};
}
```

Here is a non-compliant pseudo-iterator that does the cross product of two ranes:

```
template<class ItA, class ItB>
struct cross_iterator_t {
  range_t<ItA> cur_a;
  range_t<ItB> orig_b;
  range_t<ItB> cur_b;

  cross_iterator_t( range_t<ItA> a, range_t<ItB> b ):
    cur_a(a), orig_b(b), cur_b(b)
  {}

  bool empty() const { return cur_a.empty() || cur_b.empty(); }

  void operator++(){
    cur_b = cur_b.without_front();
    if (cur_b.empty()) {
      cur_a = cur_a.without_front();
      if (cur_a.empty()) return;
      cur_b = orig_b;
    }
  }
  auto operator*()const {
    return std::make_pair( cur_a.front(), cur_b.front() );
  }
  friend bool operator==( cross_iterator_t lhs, cross_iterator_t rhs ) {
    if (lhs.empty() && rhs.empty()) return true;

    auto mytie=[](auto&& self){
      return std::tie(self.cur_a, self.cur_b);
    };
    return mytie(lhs)==mytie(rhs);
  }
  friend bool operator!=( cross_iterator_t lhs, cross_iterator_t rhs ) {
    return !(lhs==rhs);
  }
};
template<class Lhs, class Rhs>
auto cross_iterator( range_t<Lhs> a, range_t<Rhs> b )
-> cross_iterator_t<Lhs, Rhs>
{
  return {a,b};
}
```

From this you can take `std::vector<A>, B` and do:

```
template<class A, class B>
auto cross_one_element( A& range_a, B& b_element ) {
  auto a = range( std::begin(range_a), std::end(range_a) );
  auto b = range( &b_element, (&b_element) +1 );
  auto s = cross_iterator(a, b);
  decltype(s) f{};
  return cross_iterator(s, f);
}
```

So that solves one of your problems.  The above needs to be fixed to support true input iterator featurs, not just the above pseudo-iterator that works with `for(:)`.

Then you have to write code that takes a vector of X and transorms it into a range of f(X) for some function f.

Then you have to write code that takes a range of ranges, and flattens it into a range.

Each of these steps is no harder than above.

There are libraries that do this for you.  boost has some, Rangesv3 has some, as do a pile of other range-manipulation libraries.

Boost even lets you write an iterator by specifying what to do on `*` and on next and on `==`.  Getting what to do when one of your sub-vectors is empty remains tricky, so using more generic algorithms in this case is probably wise.

The code above is not tested, and is C++14.  C++11 versions are merely more verbose.